# Get All data from one table according to another, using Temporal Tables

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables

I have two simple tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StatusForStudents](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PrimaryStatusID] [int] NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Students](
    [ID] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [IsFoster] [bit] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

With Temporal Tables feature working. Each have a `ValidFrom` and `ValidTo` fields.

I've added some dummy data:

```
insert into Students values (1,1)
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
insert into statusforstudents values (1,1)
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
insert into statusforstudents values (2,2)
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
insert into Students values (2,2)
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
insert into statusforstudents values (3,3)
```

Which got me to:

```
statusforstudents 
ValidFrom               ID  PrimaryStatusID
2020-12-14 13:18:44.25  1   1
2020-12-14 13:18:45.27  2   2
2020-12-14 13:18:47.30  3   3   


students 
ValidFrom               ID  IsFoster
2020-12-14 13:18:43.22  1   True
2020-12-14 13:18:46.28  2   True
```

I now want for each record of `statusforstudents`, to match the relevant record of `students`.
That is - for each record in `statusforstudents`, find the record of `students` that was valid at the `statusforstudents`'s time.

Or, in my example (ss for `statusforstudents`, s for `students`) the expected result would be:

```
ss.ValidFrom            ss.ID   ss.PrimaryStatusID     s.ValidFrom              s.ID  s.IsFoster
2020-12-14 13:18:44.25  1       1                      2020-12-14 13:18:43.22   1     True
2020-12-14 13:18:45.27  2       2                      2020-12-14 13:18:43.22   1     True
2020-12-14 13:18:47.30  3       3                      2020-12-14 13:18:46.28   2     True
```

I couldn't come up with anything better than just joining them, but that didn't give me anything useful..

Here's a [working example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=17bf3a1067e902dd73c96aadb8f1ddb3)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT ss.validfrom AS 'status validFrom', ss.ID, ss.PrimaryStatusID, ca.[students validFrom], ca.ID, ca.IsFoster 
FROM StatusForStudents ss
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT TOP(1) s.validfrom AS 'students validFrom', s.ID,s.IsFoster
FROM Students s 
WHERE s.validfrom<=ss.validfrom
ORDER BY s.validfrom DESC
) AS ca
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It definitely seems like it, but I thought Temporal Tables would have something "out of the box" for retrieving the relevant record from a joined table.. If it hasn't - your answer is what I was looking for. I haven't found any indication such a solution exists - I just imagined it's something that should be supported..